# mysql choose the wrong index in a multiple table join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 big tables: header, details in MySQL 8.0.22 (ubuntu 20.04.1).

details is linked to header using the foreign key (ID).
i created also an index on the date field in the details table.

so if I do:

```
select * from details where insert_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
```

it's super fast and with explain i see it's using my index.
But if I do:

```
select * from details d, header h where d.insert_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) and d.header_id = h.header_id
```

it uses the foreign key instead of my date index and it's terribly slow.

So I tried to modify the index, changing it to multiple columns (insert_date, header_id) but still mysql uses just the foreign key.

If I force the index:

```
select * from details d FORCE INDEX (iDet01), header h where d.insert_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) and d.header_id = h.header_id
```

it's super fast.

So how come mysql do not use it? Is there something I can do, or do I always have to force the index?

Thank you!

***EDIT 1:***

As Requested, this is the result with Explain analyze (i limited to 100 rows)

```
-> Limit: 100 row(s)  (cost=33239.96 rows=100) (actual time=73140.778..73148.843 rows=100 loops=1)\n    
-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=33239.96 rows=107) (actual time=73140.777..73148.835 rows=100 loops=1)\n        
-> Index lookup on x using iEve004 (TipoEvento=\'R\')  (cost=1.15 rows=9) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=2 loops=1)\n        
-> Filter: ((e.DataOraIns >= TIMESTAMP\'2020-11-24 00:00:00\') and (e.DataOraIns <= TIMESTAMP\'2020-11-25 00:00:00\'))  (cost=3323.07 rows=12) (actual time=36570.379..36574.405 rows=50 loops=2)\n            
-> Index lookup on e using fkEve003_idx (IdEsito=x.ECLID)  (cost=3323.07 rows=3703) (actual time=0.171..36462.049 rows=1277108 loops=2)\n
```

And this is the same with the index forced by me:

```
-> Limit: 100 row(s)  (cost=79703.94 rows=100) (actual time=20.747..36.088 rows=100 loops=1)\n    
-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=79703.94 rows=7215) (actual time=20.746..36.079 rows=100 loops=1)\n        
-> Filter: ((e.DataOraIns >= TIMESTAMP\'2020-11-24 00:00:00\') and (e.DataOraIns <= TIMESTAMP\'2020-11-25 00:00:00\') and (e.IdEsito is not null))  (cost=29196.14 rows=144308) (actual time=0.035..17.373 rows=33185 loops=1)\n            -> Index range scan on e using iEve004  (cost=29196.14 rows=144308) (actual time=0.033..12.003 rows=33185 loops=1)\n        -> Filter: (x.TipoEvento = \'R\')  (cost=0.25 rows=0) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=33185)\n            -> Single-row index lookup on x using PRIMARY (ECLID=e.IdEsito)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=33185)\n
```

Also, I did an analyze table before that.

***EDIT 2:***

I found something by doing different tests:

so, this uses the correct index:

```
select * 
  from details d 
 where d.insert_date >= 20201124000000 
   and d.insert_date <= 20201125000000
```

this does not:

```
select * 
  from details d, 
       header h 
 where d.insert_date >= 20201124000000
   and d.insert_date <= 20201125000000
   and d.header_id = h.header_id
```

this does:

```
select * 
  from details d, 
       header h 
 where d.insert_date >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   and d.insert_date <= now()
   and d.header_id = h.header_id
```

this does not:

```
select * 
  from details d, 
       header h 
 where d.insert_date >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   and d.insert_date <= now()
   and d.header_id = h.header_id
   and h.tipo = 'U'
```

Into the header table there was an index on "tipo" and the results were those above. However, changing the index in the header table like (header_id, tipo) and all of the above works.

but is it normal ?? (i find it strange..)

However changing the query like this (1 month):

```
select * 
  from details d, 
       header h 
 where d.insert_date >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
   and d.insert_date <= now()
   and d.header_id = h.header_id
   and h.tipo = 'U'
```

and it uses the wrong index again.

I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing, the first point is to check if your stats are up to date :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html

If you Query engine don't have relevant stat about your tables, it is bound to make some wrong move. So keeping them up to date should be a top priority if you have some change in the data.

---

For me your composite-index `insert_date, header_id` should work, but if you can edit your question with some `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-explain-analyze/ it'll help us to improve our answer.